# Using HTML in error message generated by ModelState.AddModelError()

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.1

In my ASP.NET Core Controller, I do some kind of duplicate checking. When the user try to create an Entity that already exist, he should get an error message with an link to the edit page of the duplicate entry. So I want to set this link in the message, which is set using `ModelState.AddModelError` like this:

```
if(entryIsDuplicate) {
    ModelState.AddModelError("Testfield", "Duplicate entry: View it <a href=\"" + Url.Action("Edit", new { id = existingEntry.Id }) + "\">here</a>");
}
```

Since ASP.NET Core escapes all the HTML by default for security reasons, this is not possible. And I can't simply use `@Html.Raw()`, because it's an HTML helper like this:

```
<span asp-validation-for="Testfield"></span>
```

**As a workaround, I read the error message manually by mself**

```
var testfieldError = ViewData.ModelState.Where(x => x.Value.Errors.Count > 0 && x.Key == nameof(Model.Testfield))
    .SelectMany(x => x.Value.Errors.Select(y => y.ErrorMessage))
    .ToList();

if (testfieldError != null &&  testfieldError.Count > 0) {
    var errorMessage =  testfieldError.First();
    <span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="@nameof(Model.Testfield)" data-valmsg-replace="true">@Html.Raw(errorMessage)</span>
}
```

But it would be nice to have a more generic solution using the default tag helpers. Is this possible, or do I have to write my own tag helper like `asp-html-validation-for` ?